# How do i root my HTC One S (no computer access)

Tags: rooting, htc-one

Hello I have a question I hope you have a answer to. I have a HTC One S and I would love to root it although I have no computer access. Is there any way I can root my device?

Comment: See **Methods/apps** in the answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/96277).

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and install framaroot in your device that should work